# How to prevent a line break to every html element end tag using VSCode Prettier?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade, prettier

This what I currently have on my Editor. This is actually a laravel blade, so the filename is `page.blade.php`. However, I added these on the `files.associate`;

```
"*.blade.php":"html"
```

```
<nav
    class="navbar navbar-standard navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark navbar-theme"
>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html"
            ><span class="text-white">{{ config("app.name") }}</span></a
        >
        <button
            class="navbar-toggler collapsed"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarStandard"
            aria-controls="navbarStandard"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

So if you notice on the snippet,  the `>` is always breaking the line and it's not good. especially on the `</a>` tag. I tried editing the `HTML>Format: Wrapp Attributes`, but it's not working, see picture attached:

[image: vs-code settings]

Now this is what I want.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-standard navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark navbar-theme">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html">
            <span class="text-white">Logo</span>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarStandard" aria-controls="navbarStandard" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: Just click on Right bottom plain text, it will open a dialog box type html and SELECT html]

[image: Then right click and select format document. It will format file like you want]

Just click on Right bottom plain text, it will open a dialog box type html and Select HTML. see Picture 1.

Then right click and select format document. It will format file like you want. See Picture 2.